# Validation Settings Not Showing in List Settings SP2013

Tags: 2013, list, validation

I can't see an option for Validation Settings or Catalog Settings for my list in SP2013. What permissions should my admin provide me in order for those two options to show?

[These are the settings that are available.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HaAk.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Full Control permissions are needed.